# /sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia_settings.conf

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, nvidia-settings

After upgrading from ubuntu 16.04 all the way to ubuntu 18.04 im seeing a lot of messeges like this during apt-get upgrade.

`/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia_settings.conf`

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia_settings.conf: No such file or directory
```

Sometimes my nvidia driver loads, simetimes it does not.
I'm currently using the ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa.
I've tried purging nvidia several times.
Would like to not have to fresh install.
It looks like the problem is that symbolic link for nvidia_settings_conf is going nowhere, but I'm not sure where it is supposed to be.

Output nvidia-smi

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.77                 Driver Version: 390.77                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 770     Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 34%   39C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    102MiB /  1991MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Output of 'ls -al /etc/ld.so.conf.d/'

```
➜  ~ ls -al /etc/ld.so.conf.d/
total 40
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 mai    2 19:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 206 root root 16384 juli  21 17:11 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    38 mars  24  2014 fakeroot-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   168 april 16 22:14 i386-linux-gnu.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    44 aug.   9  2009 libc.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    26 des.  26  2017 local.conf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    38 mai   14  2014 nvidia_settings.conf -> /etc/alternatives/nvidia_settings_conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   100 april 16 22:14 x86_64-linux-gnu.conf

➜  ~ ls -al /etc/alternatives/ | grep nvidia
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    41 mai   14  2014 libxnvctrl.a -> /usr/lib/nvidia-settings-319/libXNVCtrl.a
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    72 mai   14  2014 man_nvidiasettings.gz -> /usr/lib/nvidia-settings-319/share/man/man1/alt-nvidia-settings-319.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    43 mai   14  2014 nvctrl_include -> /usr/lib/nvidia-settings-319/include/NVCtrl
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    48 mai   14  2014 nvidia_settings -> /usr/lib/nvidia-settings-319/bin/nvidia-settings
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    39 mai   14  2014 nvidia_settings_conf -> /usr/lib/nvidia-settings-319/ld.so.conf

ls -al /usr/lib/ | grep nvidia
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1467112 mai    2 23:00 libnvidia-gtk2.so.396.24
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1475784 mai    2 23:00 libnvidia-gtk3.so.396.24
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 mai    2 18:09 nvidia
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 aug.   4  2014 nvidia-319
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 nov.  19  2015 nvidia-346
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 mai    2 18:55 nvidia-390
```

Comment: And the results of `ls -l  /usr/lib/nvidia-settings-319/ld.so.conf` are??? So far, it looks like that particular file does not exist.

Comment: Yes as you can see from the output of ls -al /usr/lib the folder /usr/lib/nvidia-settings-319 does not even exist. And I am running 390 driver, so why would it need nviidia_setings.conf from 319? No idea.

Comment: Maybe i should try to delete it and run ldconfig -a?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar warning after upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04

I have removed `nvidia-settings.conf` from `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` since it was pointing to files which did not exist. So far so good...

Answer (score 0):

```
server:/etc/ld.so.conf.d$ sudo mv nvidia_settings.conf OLD_nvidia_settings.conf_OLD
```

Link of this file to /etc/alternatives/nvidia_settings.conf was broken, rename to **OLD**_nvidia_settings.conf_**OLD** in /etc/ld.so.conf.d as you don't know if something is looking for a file starting with nvidia_settings....

Answer (score 0):

The issue is kinda plain to see. The error is showing:

`/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia_settings.conf`

But the actual link is `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia_settings_conf`

WRONG: nvidia_settings.conf

> CORRECT: nvidia_settings_conf

Rename the link and it works.